# Pass a method in a function

Tags: javascript, html

How can I pass a method to a function?

Ex:

```
alert(myFunc('id'));
function myFunc(method){
   return document.getElementById('ele').method;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why are you returning the method rather than calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use bracket notation for that, and you need to make sure the method exists or you'll see errors in the console.

```
return document.getElementById('ele')[method];
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need bracket notation

```
function myFunc(method){
   return document.getElementById('ele')[method];
}
```

That way you could do

```
myFunc('style');
```

Note that returning functions, commonly known as methods, like `click` and then trying to call them, would be an illegal invocation.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like you've done it. To prove that it works, just return a string from the method.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    alert(myFunc('id'));
    function myFunc(method){
        return 'hi';
    }
</script
</body>
```